# Laravel Nested Children Count (Categories)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, adjacency-list

I using nested categories on my Laravel site with an adjacentcy list style mysql table layout. There is a maximum of 7 layers of categorization, (using [google categories taxonomy](https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy-with-ids.en-US.txt)). Please see the image below for a small sample of data, and the code below for my Category model's relationships.

Each category has zero to many subcategories (using same Category Model), as well as zero to many pages underneath it. **My goal here is to find a way to get a count of all pages beneath a category (including pages under its subcategories).**

[image: MySql Table Layout Example]

My Category model has the following relationships which are all functioning:

```
public function pages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Page');
}

public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id' );
}

public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id' );
}

public function childrenRecursive() {
   return $this->children()->orderBy( 'name' )->with('childrenRecursive', 'pages');
}

public function parentRecursive() {
   return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir nope! I haven't even found the brain power to think up one way to accomplish it. Other than just looping through everything and counting but that would take forever on pages I need to show a lot of categories.

Comment: That would be the "normal" approach. With eager loading, this should be reasonably fast. How do you want to use the number of pages?

Comment: Well there are pages that display all of the categories -- so like 5000, but maybe I could set it up so it's not awful! I want to use the number of pages to display how many pages are in the categories (like on an admin page, or on a big sitemap page)

Comment: If your pages and categories don't change very often, you could consider storing the number of pages in a column in the `categories` table.

Comment: Unfortunatly we're adding pages all the time. So I don't think that's a great idea ):

Comment: Try the "looping through everything and counting" solution with eager loading. If it's too slow, report back.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir this is suprisingly not slowing me down. Thank you! I should have tried this on my own at first!

Comment: Can you post your code as an answer here?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir done! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I am eager loading all of these categories and pages in the first palce using the following line of code and my Categories model:

```
$categories = Category::with( 'childrenRecursive' )->whereNull( 'parent_id' )->get();
```

I was able to use a recursive formula to sum up the number of pages underneath each category without slowing down the page:

```
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $category->pagesCount = 0;
    $category->pagesCount += $category->pages->count();
    foreach( $category->childrenRecursive as $child ) {
        $category->pagesCount += countChildPages( $child );
    }
}

function countChildPages( $category ) {
    $category->pagesCount = 0;
    $category->pagesCount += $category->pages->count();
    foreach( $category->childrenRecursive as $child ) {
        $category->pagesCount += countChildPages( $child );
    }
    return $category->pagesCount;
}
```

I then just accessed the count ($category->pagesCount) whenever I needed to use it on the page.

---

**Example** of sitemap.html page:

```
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $category->pagesCount = 0;
    $category->pagesCount += $category->pages->count();
    foreach( $category->childrenRecursive as $child ) {
        $category->pagesCount += countChildPages( $child );
    }
}

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if( $category->pagesCount > 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="category">';
            echo '<h2><a href="https://example.com/' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . ' (' . $category->pagesCount . ')</a></h2>';
            foreach( $category->pages as $page ) {
                showPage( $page );
            }
            foreach( $category->childrenRecursive as $child ) {
                showSubCategory( $child );
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

function countChildPages( $category ) {
    $category->pagesCount = 0;
    $category->pagesCount += $category->pages->count();
    foreach( $category->childrenRecursive as $child ) {
        $category->pagesCount += countChildPages( $child );
    }
    return $category->pagesCount;
}

function showSubCategory( $category ) {
    if( $category->pagesCount > 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="category">';
            echo '<h2><a href="https://example.com/' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . ' (' . $category->pagesCount . ')</a></h2>';
            foreach( $category->pages as $page ) {
                showPage( $page );
            }
            foreach( $category->childrenRecursive as $child ) {
                showSubCategory( $child );
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

function showPage( $page ) {
    echo '<div class="category page">';
        echo '<h2><a href="https://example.com/' . $page->slug . '">' . $page->title . '</a></h2>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how I would do it using relationships, but a sneaky way would be:

```
public function childCount(){
  return DB::table('categories')->where('slug', 'LIKE', $this->slug . '%')->count() - 1;
}
```

To get the pages, maybe:

```
public function pageCount(){
  return Page::whereIn('category_id', 
     DB::table('categories')->select('id')->where('slug', 'LIKE', $this->slug . '%')->get()->pluck('id')
  )->count();
}
```

2 queries which could probably be optimized, but would work

Comment: This counts the number of subcategories that the category has, but it doesn't count the number of pages.

Comment: Jonas was smart enough to say just try it the old fashion way lol. But i am going to give this a shot and see if it's any faster! Thank you!