# How to Show Subcategory Count beside each Parent Category in Laravel

Tags: laravel, categories

in my laravel application I have categories and subcategories in the same db table. Any Category with NULL in parent column is a parent category while any category with an ID in its parent column is a subcategory.

[image]

In my view table I want to have the number of subcategories beside each parent category but I don't know how to pass the number of each subcategory along with the parent category from the control to view
[image]

```
public function index()
{
    //select parent categories
    $arr['categories'] = Category::where('parent', NULL)->orderBy('category', 'asc')->get();
    return view("admin.categories")->with($arr);
    
}

 @foreach($categories as $item)
 <td>{{$count++}}</td>
 <td>{{$item->category}}</td>
 <td>#</td>
 <td>@if($item->id != 0) 
 <a href="categories/{{$item->id}}/edit"><img src="{{asset('assets/images/edit.png')}}" alt="Update" title="Update" width="20" align="left" style="margin-right:20px;"></a>

 <form action="{{ url('admin/categories' , $item->id ) }}" method="POST">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
 <input type="image" src="{{asset('assets/images/delete.png')}}" alt="Delete" title="Delete" width="20" onClick="return deleteItem();">
 @endif</td>

 @endforeach
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Nested Children Count (Categories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197613/laravel-nested-children-count-categories) Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216892/how-to-get-the-count-and-values-of-item-in-a-subcategory-with-parent-id-in-larav

Answer (score 1):

**App\Models\Category.php**

```
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

**App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    //select parent categories
    $arr['categories'] = Category::withCount('subcategory')->where('parent', NULL)->orderBy('category', 'asc')->get();
    return view("admin.categories")->with($arr);
    
}
```

**resources\views\admin\categories.blade.php**

```
@foreach($categories as $item)
...
    <td>{{ $item->subcategory_count }}</td>

...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue rectified. I just added in to my Category Model

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'parent');
}
```

and added this to my view

```
{{@count($item->subCategories)}}
@foreach($item->subCategories as $subCaty)
    {{$subCaty->category}},
@endforeach
```

that did the magic

I got the help from youtube.com/watch?v=1N8KoF4H218